# extracting a value from a nested list using a specific index

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested-lists

so i basically have a nested list that will be constantly changing but for example it will look like this:

```
[9,1,[3,5][3]]
```

and then I'm also getting a generated index that's formatted like this:

```
[2,1]
```

so, at index `[2,1]` the value is '5' but how do I write code that will automatically extract this value for me? the list will be constantly changing and the indexes will also be changing (will always be a valid index) so I cant just used a nested for loop. is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: just loop over the generated index and grab the element from the nested list that matches the current index in the loop

Comment: `[3,5][3]` isn't valid. You meant `[3,5], [3]`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through the required index, and use `<list>.pop(<index>)` to extract the element using its index.

```
L = [9,1,[3,5],[3]]
idx = [2,1]

for i in idx:
    L = L.pop(i)
print(L)
```

Output

`5`

Answer (score 1):

If your index isn't changing in dimension, maybe you could just use the hard-coded value?
If they are changing, you can iterate with your indexes and pop the items, until you reach your item index.

```
lst = [9, 1, [3, 5], [3]]
idx = [2, 1]

print(lst[idx[0]][idx[1]])

// or 
for i in idx:
    lst = lst.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `L` to `c` and loop over `indices` and In each loop you will get one level deeper until you reach the final value.

```py
L = [9,1,[3,5],[3]]
indices = [2,1]
c = L.copy()
for i in indices:
    c = c[i]
print(c) #5
```